# Formatting the bibliography with different date

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I would like to format my date in the bibliography as following:

```
Greenwade, G. D. (19 Februari 2015). The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network (CTAN).
TUGBoat, 14 (3), 342–351
```

But I keep ending up with:

```
Greenwade, G. D. (2015). The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network (CTAN).
TUGBoat, 14 (3), 342–351
```

How can I override this behaviour?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa, % <-- I need this APA format in the text
dateabbrev=false
]{biblatex}

\title{A bibLaTeX example}
\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file

% default bibliography environment (from biblatex.sty)
\defbibenvironment{bibliography} 
  {\list{}{%
     \leftmargin\bibhang 
     \itemindent-\leftmargin 
     \itemsep\bibitemsep
      \parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

% 'numeric' bibliography environment (from numeric.bbx)
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}%
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\begin{document}
\section{First section}

Items that are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \parencite{latexcompanion} together with Einstein's journal paper \parencite{einstein} and Dirac's book \cite{dirac}---which are physics-related items. Next, citing two of Knuth's books: \textit{Fundamental Algorithms} \parencite{knuth-fa} and \textit{The Art of Computer Programming} \parencite{knuth-acp}.

\medskip
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=TITLE]
\end{document}
```

`sample.bib`

```latex
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
 
@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = "1973",
   chapter = "1.2",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@article{ctan,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    date = {2015-02-19},
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your posting to show the bib entry (or entries) in question.

Comment: @Mico I have updated my post.

Comment: As far as I understand it is APA style not to include more specific date info for `@article`s. Is there any specific reason why you would need that here?

Comment: That is true, I'm looking for a blent, in the text I would like to have: `(author, year)`, and in the bibliography I would like to have the full date `(dd mm yy)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed it by changing:

```latex
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
```

to:

```latex
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, labeldate=comp]{biblatex}
```

And overriding the default retrieved and from parameter with my own style:

```latex
\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
    retrieved = {Geraadpleegd op},
    from      = {van},
}
```

And using the correct date format in the `.bib` file, thanks to **@moewe**:

```latex
@online{kmm,
    title = {Kotlin Multiplatform},
    author = {JetBrains},
    date = {2023-02-14},
    url = {https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html},
    urldate = {2023-02-14},
}
```

Results in the following:

[image: Correct bib layout]

Comment: It might not give the exact same wording as your output, but `addendum = {Geraadpleegd op: 14 februari 2023 van \url{https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html}},` would more idiomatically be `url = {https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html}, urldate = {2023-02-14},` in `biblatex`.